# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float - Variables in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, integer

I'm new to programing so forgive me if my questions are on the obvious side.
Essentially I am trying to create a basic polar coordinate system for use in Tkinter, however, I'm having some issues with it.

Here are the relevant bits of code:

```
def polar(self, theta, radius, xC, yC):
    thetarad = -theta * (math.pi / 180)
    xprime = xC + math.cos(thetarad) * radius
    yprime = yC + math.sin(thetarad) * radius
    return (xprime, yprime)

def draw(self, c):        

    # create X-coordinate guide list
    xspaces = 55    # number of guides in the guide list
    xgridwidth = 1.0 * self.width / xspaces
    x = []
    for i in range(xspaces+1):
        x.append(self.left + i*xgridwidth)

    # create Y-coordinate guide list
    yspaces = 100    # number of guides in the guide list
    ygridwidth = 1.0 * self.height / yspaces
    y = []
    for i in range(yspaces+1):
        y.append(self.top + i*ygridwidth)


    xC = x[30]
    yC = y[25]

    theta = 0
    radius = 15
    [xprime, yprime]=self.polar(theta, radius, xC, yC)
    petalp1 = (  (x[xprime], y[yprime])  )
```

The top and bottom most parts are what I'm getting the errors with. Essentially I just need xprime and yprime to come back as integer numbers so they can be used just as well as raw numbers when establishing p1. Help is appreciated.

Full error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:FileName.py", line 34, in <module>
    daisy.draw(c)
  File "E:FileName2.py", line 174, in draw
    petalp1 = (x[int(xprime)], y[int(yprime)])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: And what's the problem that you're seeing?

Comment: On the very last line if I have "p1 = (  (xprime, yprime)  )" Then it is no problem, but I need it to be in the form "p1 = (  (x[xprime], y[yprime])  )". And for some reason I can't get xprime or yprime to act as an integer that Tkinter requires.

Comment: Why do you need the extra brackets `((x[xprime], y[yprime]))`? Can you not just do `(x[xprime], y[yprime])` ?

Comment: And are you sure the line above you didn't mean (note the change in square to round brackets) : `(xprime, yprime) = self.polar(theta, radius, xC, yC)`

Comment: Edited comment completely: The square to round brackets seems to make no difference. Same error.

Comment: That's the stacktrace we need to see, update your post. You should just be able to run `int(variable)` for whatever it needs to be an integer. I'm guessing `x[int(xprime)], y[int(yprime)]` or something similar.

Comment: I tried that and now I'm getting a "IndexError: list index out of range". Edit: also, "stacktrace"?

Comment: Wherever you're seeing `IndexError: ...`, update your post with all of that.

Comment: Hopefully that is what you were after. The first file that it is referencing is a very basic draw file with a few parameters that haven't given me any trouble.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `xprime` and `yprime` as indexes into your `x` and `y` lists? They're already coordinates, so probably you want to just use the tuple `xprime, yprime`, rather than what you are currently attempting.

Comment: I'm aware this isn't the best system but I'm still pretty new to this. Care to inform me about tuples or give me a quick example on how that would work here?

Comment: Almost any time you separate two values by a comma, you're using a tuple. You're already doing this! Tuples are one of the basic types in Python, you can read about them in [the Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). Note that the parentheses and square brackets you're using at the end are mostly not needed (you can use `xprime, yprime = self.polar(theta, radius, xC, yC)` and `petalp1 = xprime, yprime`). I'm not sure that this is what you really want (since I don't know what `petalp1` is for), but it will at least be legal Python.

Comment: Essentially I am trying to draw an object where petalp1 is a single point on that object. It works fine for a single point without the brackets and what have you but the program allows for the entire thing to shift/stretch as an entire object. When I turn `petalp1 = x[xprime], y[yprime]` into `petalp1 = xprime, yprime` Then it creates and object that can't be stretched or changed.. although it doesn't give me any errors.

Comment: Check values of `int(xprime)` and `int(yprime)`.  `int(xprime)` can't be smaller than `0` and bigger then `xspaces`. `int(yprime)` can't be smaller than `0` and bigger then `yspaces`

Answer (score 1):

Seems `int(xprime)` is bigger then `xspaces` (value: 55) and `int(yprime)` is bigger then `yspaces` (value: 100) so you try to get values not existing in list `x` (length: 55) and in list `y` (length: 100) ( `x[int(xprime)]` and `y[int(yprime)]` )

Comment: Changing the values seems to make no difference. The same "index out of range" error pops up. Appreciate the idea though.

Comment: `list index out of range` means `int(xprime)` and/or `int(yprime)` in too big in `x[int(xprime)]` and/or `y[int(yprime)]`. Or size of list `x[]` and/or `y[]` is too small. I try to run your code (using `width=800, height=600, left=0, top=0`)  and I get `int(xprime) == 451` and `int(yprime) == 150` so `x[451]` and `y[150]` is out of the list. For `width=55` and `height=100` I get `int(xprime) == 45` and `int(yprime) == 15` so `x[45]` and `y[15]` is in list. I didn't know what `width` and `height` you have.